# If there is a ground potential (V = 0), is there a ground current?

Tags: basic

Can current be defined with respect to some "ground current"? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by defined relative to? Unlike voltage, where we are primarily interested in relative potential differences, in most cases current is an absolute value (charge per time between two points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If \$q\$ reprsents a quanitity of charge passing a a single arbitrary point in space, then current is defined **relative** to time as:

$$i=\frac{dq}{dt}$$

A voltage at a point in space is defined **relative** to another point in space.

> Can current be defined with respect to some "ground current"?

Simply, No! Current has no referenceto ground, but may flow through it whether the ground potential is zero or not. We often refer to ground as being zero volts, but this is arbitrary. Two separated grounds may have differing potentials.